# Issues with using FFmpeg to generate MPEG-DASH files

Tags: ffmpeg, video-streaming, http-live-streaming, exoplayer, mpeg-dash

I am using the following `ffmpeg` command to generate MPEG DASH files and manifest. I use `single_file 1` to have a single file for each representation; so no chunking. But IDK why when I want to play the manifest using ExoPlayer, the video doesn't play from the beginning (rather it starts from around 50s).

```
ffmpeg -re -i .\video-h264.mkv -map 0 -map 0 -c:a aac -c:v libx264 -b:v:0 800k -b:v:1 300k -s:v:1 320x170 -profile:v:1 baseline -profile:v:0 main -bf 1 -keyint_min 120 -g 120 -sc_threshold 0 -b_strategy 0 -ar:a:1 22050 -use_timeline 1 -single_file 1 -use_template 1 -window_size 5 -adaptation_sets "id=0,streams=v id=1,streams=a" -f dash out.mpd
```

What is wrong with this? Is the manifest correct? Here is the generated mpd:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<MPD xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="urn:mpeg:dash:schema:mpd:2011"
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
    xsi:schemaLocation="urn:mpeg:DASH:schema:MPD:2011 http://standards.iso.org/ittf/PubliclyAvailableStandards/MPEG-DASH_schema_files/DASH-MPD.xsd"
    profiles="urn:mpeg:dash:profile:isoff-live:2011"
    type="static"
    mediaPresentationDuration="PT1M20.1S"
    maxSegmentDuration="PT5.0S"
    minBufferTime="PT16.0S">
    <ProgramInformation>
    </ProgramInformation>
    <ServiceDescription id="0">
    </ServiceDescription>
    <Period id="0" start="PT48.0S">
        <AdaptationSet id="0" contentType="video" startWithSAP="1" segmentAlignment="true" bitstreamSwitching="true" frameRate="30/1" maxWidth="960" maxHeight="540" par="517072:290799" lang="eng">
            <Representation id="0" mimeType="video/mp4" codecs="avc1.4d401f" bandwidth="800000" width="960" height="540" sar="32317:32311">
                <BaseURL>out-stream0.mp4</BaseURL>
                <SegmentList timescale="1000000" duration="5000000" startNumber="7">
                    <Initialization range="0-832" />
                    <SegmentURL mediaRange="4800141-5599188" indexRange="4800141-4800192" />
                    <SegmentURL mediaRange="5599189-6243069" indexRange="5599189-5599240" />
                    <SegmentURL mediaRange="6243070-7224302" indexRange="6243070-6243121" />
                    <SegmentURL mediaRange="7224303-8138118" indexRange="7224303-7224354" />
                    <SegmentURL mediaRange="8138119-8232111" indexRange="8138119-8138170" />
                </SegmentList>
            </Representation>
            <Representation id="2" mimeType="video/mp4" codecs="avc1.42c00d" bandwidth="300000" width="320" height="170" sar="549389:581598">
                <BaseURL>out-stream2.mp4</BaseURL>
                <SegmentList timescale="1000000" duration="5000000" startNumber="7">
                    <Initialization range="0-832" />
                    <SegmentURL mediaRange="1782920-2005667" indexRange="1782920-1782971" />
                    <SegmentURL mediaRange="2005668-2229412" indexRange="2005668-2005719" />
                    <SegmentURL mediaRange="2229413-2615209" indexRange="2229413-2229464" />
                    <SegmentURL mediaRange="2615210-2975346" indexRange="2615210-2615261" />
                    <SegmentURL mediaRange="2975347-2999288" indexRange="2975347-2975398" />
                </SegmentList>
            </Representation>
        </AdaptationSet>
        <AdaptationSet id="1" contentType="audio" startWithSAP="1" segmentAlignment="true" bitstreamSwitching="true" lang="eng">
            <Representation id="1" mimeType="audio/mp4" codecs="mp4a.40.2" bandwidth="69000" audioSamplingRate="44100">
                <AudioChannelConfiguration schemeIdUri="urn:mpeg:dash:23003:3:audio_channel_configuration:2011" value="1" />
                <BaseURL>out-stream1.mp4</BaseURL>
                <SegmentList timescale="1000000" duration="5000000" startNumber="12">
                    <Initialization range="0-764" />
                    <SegmentURL mediaRange="491493-536039" indexRange="491493-491544" />
                    <SegmentURL mediaRange="536040-580657" indexRange="536040-536091" />
                    <SegmentURL mediaRange="580658-625158" indexRange="580658-580709" />
                    <SegmentURL mediaRange="625159-669825" indexRange="625159-625210" />
                    <SegmentURL mediaRange="669826-713289" indexRange="669826-669877" />
                </SegmentList>
            </Representation>
            <Representation id="3" mimeType="audio/mp4" codecs="mp4a.40.2" bandwidth="69000" audioSamplingRate="22050">
                <AudioChannelConfiguration schemeIdUri="urn:mpeg:dash:23003:3:audio_channel_configuration:2011" value="1" />
                <BaseURL>out-stream3.mp4</BaseURL>
                <SegmentList timescale="1000000" duration="5000000" startNumber="12">
                    <Initialization range="0-764" />
                    <SegmentURL mediaRange="486188-530059" indexRange="486188-486239" />
                    <SegmentURL mediaRange="530060-574175" indexRange="530060-530111" />
                    <SegmentURL mediaRange="574176-618922" indexRange="574176-574227" />
                    <SegmentURL mediaRange="618923-663118" indexRange="618923-618974" />
                    <SegmentURL mediaRange="663119-706121" indexRange="663119-663170" />
                </SegmentList>
            </Representation>
        </AdaptationSet>
    </Period>
</MPD>
```

Comment: You use `window_size` and keep only the last 5 segments.

Comment: Your Period start time: <Period id="0" start="PT48.0S">
is responsible for starting around 50 seconds but I don't know how it got there.

Comment: @aergistal you were right. I removed the `-window_size 5` and it works now. If you like, pls write this and I give you the best answer credit!

Answer (score 1):

you need to remove
-window_size 5
it keeps only 5 segments of video in mpd

https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#dash-2